# how to parse a string with html tags in its substrings which are bold, italic, underlined

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I created some kind of text rendering tool for a 2D graphics framework in c#.

Now i was trying to parse a text with specific html tags in it, like:

```
"Hello <b>world</b>!"
```

But the parsing code was getting ugly and I thought, there must be some lib that does exactly that. At the end it should output an array of data structures like:

```
string text;
bool IsBold;
bool IsItalic;
bool IsUnderlined;
...
```

or

```
string text;
FontStyle FontStyle;
```

Anyone know of such a parser?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How should your code react to inputs such as `"<b>hel</b>lo"`?

Comment: then only 'hel' is bold. it would output an array of 2 data structures.. 'hel' with IsBold = true, and 'lo' with IsBold = false.

Comment: Well, what about the following input? `"<b><i>hi</i> there</b>, you"`. Clearly, an array won’t suffice once you allow nested markup.

Comment: thats exactly is my question.. in that case it should output the following entries in the array: "hi" with IsBold = true and IsItalic = true, then "there" with IsBold = true and IsItalic = false, then ", you" with IsBold = false and IsItalic = false.. does that makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good HTML parser (and also parses fragments).

You can query it using XPath syntax (it is similar to XmlDocument) - not sure how good a fit it will be for your requirements.

Comment: that was leading me to the System.Xml.XPath namespace. now i can select some text which is in the tag <b> with "/parenttag/b", but how would i get my individual text slices when there are nested tags like <b><i>text</i> more text</b> ...?

Comment: @thalm - that would involve selecting `::text()` nodes in your XPath.

Comment: not exactly sure how that would solve the nested tag problem..?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how this would work, but here are some HTML parsers:
[html_parse](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php)
[htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Tidy.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/) is a fantastic tool which is a port from the original Tidy project which is used in the HTML Tidy firefox plugin. Run your code through Tidy and it will return clean, compliant html.